# How to find the value that give the global maximum of a function?

Tags: matlab, log-likelihood

I have got the following function:

$$L(x,y) = \frac{(16.2x +0.9y+5.2)^{24} e^{-(16.2x +0.9y+5.2)}}{24!} \cdot \frac{(2.1x +4.2y+0.9)^8 e^{-(2.1x +4.2y+0.9)}}{8!} \tag{1}$$

and I am attempting at finding the values for x and y that give me the global maximum.

---

I have attempted doing this using MATLAB by setting an equal range for the x and y coordinates, and using *islocalmax(L)*,but I simply get a row of 0s and 1s.

**Can this be done any other way?**

Comment: Use $\texttt{fmincon}$ on $L$ and use $[0;0]$ as initial value.  This should give you something like $(-0.303693188008090, -0.181026096343822 )^\top$ as minimizer. Function looks convex at first sight, so I think this should be the only one.

Comment: Guess you could also try to implement gradient descent with Armijo-Rule. But it's not huge fun to implement the derivative...

Comment: What if I don't know the initial value? My colleague has stated that the result should be:$(1.10, 1.14)$, but this seems to be different from your results, could it be due to a different start point?

Comment: There is a very nice answer. Taking $log$ of course works. I should examine if I made mistakes once again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Done by hand.*

For the coordinates of the maximum, forget the factorial and take the logarithm of the function and compute the partial derivatives

$$\frac{\partial\log[L(x,y)]}{\partial x}=\frac{56}{7 x+14 y+3}+\frac{3888}{162 x+9 y+52}-\frac{183}{10}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial\log[L(x,y)]}{\partial y}=\frac{112}{7 x+14 y+3}+\frac{216}{162 x+9 y+52}-\frac{51}{10}=0$$ which is more than simple if you let
$$A=\frac{1}{7 x+14 y+3} \qquad \text{and} \qquad B=\frac{1}{162 x+9 y+52}$$ Two linear equations in $(A,B)$ which, back to $(x,y)$ give
$$x=\frac{2419}{2205}\qquad \text{and} \qquad y=\frac{2518}{2205}$$

Comment: That is perfect, thank you so much